# create csv from Azure function and upload network folder

Tags: azure-functions

I have created azure function to create csv now need to know how to connect network folder and upload csv to the folder .
Already hybrid connection in place and not sure how to access the folder through code

Answer (score 0):

Yes I manage to achieve this buy Connecting to on-premises data sources with On-premises data gateway https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-gateway

steps followed to achieve this:

-create gateway to connect on-prem server (network folder)

- Azure function - copy file to Azure blob
- Logic App to copy file from Azure blob to Network folder using File system connector(this connector uses the gate way to connect network folder created previously)

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible to mount a SMB drive through the hybrid connector. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections#things-you-cannot-do-with-hybrid-connections

Also discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55789358/1537195

Best workaround that comes to my mind:

- Write the CSV file from your function to an Azure Blob Storage
- Use [Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-file-system) with self-hosted Integration Runtime to copy the file to your network share